# How to show the title of a MarkerOptions Marker on a Map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I add some markers to a map like this:

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
markerOptions.position(new LatLng(foo.lat, foo.lon)).title(foo.name);
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

How to show the title of a Marken then on the map, like when a user clicks on it?

Comment: you can try forcing the infowindow by calling `marker.showInfoWindow()`

Comment: but how to access the marker if I only have the markerOptions?

Comment: `mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` returns a marker, you should probably look at the documentation for google maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mMap.addMarker()` returns a marker using that marker object you can try forcing the `InfoWindow` open using

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```